# Restructure data in javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

If I wanted to turn this data structure:

```
time = [
{id: 'actual', summed: 24000},
{id: 'plan', summed: 8000}
]
```

in the following data structure using JavaScript or lodash, what would be the best approach?

```
time = {
actual: 24000,
plan: 8000
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let time = [{ id: 'actual', summed: 24000 }, { id: 'plan', summed: 8000 }]
let obj = time.reduce((acc, {id, summed}) => ({...acc, [id] : summed}),{})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted key/value pairs and build an object from it.

```js
const
    time = [{ id: 'actual', summed: 24000 }, { id: 'plan', summed: 8000 }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(time.map(({ id, summed }) => [id, summed]));

console.log(result);
```